# WPF Animate Image Source - Images Fail To Load

Tags: c#, wpf, image, animation, jquery-animate

I want to animate the Source property of an image in WPF using a ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.

My images "0.png" and "1.png" are in a folder called "Assets". Both have "Build Action" set to "Resource".

I load the images like this:

```
private readonly ImageSource[] images = new ImageSource[]
{
   new BitmapImage(new Uri("Assets/0.png", UriKind.Relative)),
   new BitmapImage(new Uri("Assets/1.png", UriKind.Relative))
};
```

Create an animation:

```
ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames anim = new ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
anim.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
anim.KeyFrames.Add(new DiscreteObjectKeyFrame(images[0]));
anim.KeyFrames.Add(new DiscreteObjectKeyFrame(images[1]));
```

And attempt to apply it to an image:

```
MyImage.BeginAnimation(Image.SourceProperty, anim);
```

This gives a System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException "Could not find a part of the path ...".

Here is the weird part. I can set the source of my Image without any problems. So there shouldn't be any problems with the path.

```
MyImage.Source = images[0];
MyImage.Source = images[1];
```

In fact if I have used my images as a source before beginning the animation, then it works! So it seems like the images are not loaded correctly when using the animation.

```
MyImage.Source = images[0];
MyImage.Source = images[1];
MyImage.BeginAnimation(Image.SourceProperty, anim); // This works now !?!
```

Is this a bug?
Can I force the images to be loaded correctly before starting the animation (Without having to use them as a source first for no reason) ?.

Comment: For assembly resources use [Resource File Pack URIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8), e.g. `new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Assets/0.png"))`. If you had used `"Assets/0.png"` in XAML, the Pack URI prefix was automatically prepended by the XAML Parser.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It does indeed work when I use ```new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Assets/0.png"))```. I just don't understand why it doesn't work with a relative pack URI. 

In the section "Using Pack URIs in Code" of the link you sent me, it looks like the same file can be accessed using either an absolute or a relative pack URI.

```Uri absoluteUri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/File.xaml", UriKind.Absolute);
Uri relativeUri = new Uri("/File.xaml",UriKind.Relative);```

Comment: That should indeed also work, no idea why it did not for you. Using an absolute URI is however more clear.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your help